# Xpath - select element with attribute and take another attribute value

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom, xpath

I have this code:

```
 <li datetime="2019-06-03T14:45" offset="-135" type="standard"></li>
... etc.
```

How I can get `datetime` attribute value if all elements contain attribute `type` with value `standard`? So how I can get `datetime` value (2019-06-03T14:45) from each `li` element

I tried:

```
$timeslots = [];
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query('//li[@type="standard"])/@datetime');

foreach($entries as $e) {
  $timeslots[] = $e->textContent;
}

$ts = $timeslots;
return $ts;
```

but I got an error:

> DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Comment: Think it's the extra `)` in `li[@type="standard"])/`

Comment: thanks, thats correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought the issue is resolved, I just want to provide the idea how you can quickly check your xpath [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

This will give you the message if xpath is not correct and you can get idea what's wrong.

[image]